# =& operator in PHP

Tags: php, operators

Example:

$this->sql =& new GuestBook_SQL;

What does it do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This operator is assigning reference. [Here's](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php) the explenation from PHP manual

Answer (score 2):

It assigns by reference, instead of by value.

Answer (score 1):

And it's old. You don't need that syntax anymore in PHP5. It assigns new objects by reference anyway.